# Cannot Feed UITableView with .plist

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, plist

I am a beginner and have a probably quite simple question. I browsed through similar topics and lost a day without finding a solution.
I have a Master and Detail view controllers. I created a .plist as shown below.
[image: plist]

Now I would like feed UITableView with these data. And here the problem is. I can't take continents names. All the time I see blank cells or I get some errors. Maybe I should change something in the plist?

Here is my code:
MasterViewController.h:

```
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *world;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *africa;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *europe;

@end
```

MasterViewController.m (the places where I added something):

```
@synthesize world, africa, europe;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.navigationItem.title = @"World Info";
NSString *worldLibraryFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"World" ofType:@"plist"];
world = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:worldLibraryFile];
africa = [world objectForKey:@"Africa"];
europe = [world objectForKey:@"Europe"];

[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [world count]; //this works fine
}
```

And here I have a problem:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


NSString *ContinentName = [world objectForKey:indexPath.row]; //I do something wrong here
cell.textLabel.text = ContinentName;

return cell;
}
```

How can I get my continents shown in the table view? How to get countries and then other info shown after another clicks?

Thank you for any help.

It works now, after these changes:

```
NSArray *namesOfContintents = [world allKeys];
NSString *ContinentName = [namesOfContintents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = ContinentName;
```

I also wanted to add some subtitles to the cells. I added:

```
int numberEurope;
numberEurope = [europe count];

int numberAfrica;
numberAfrica = [africa count];

NSNumber *myNum1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:numberEurope];
NSNumber *myNum2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:numberAfrica];

NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: myNum1, myNum2, nil];

cell.textLabel.text = ContinentName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ countries", myArray];
return cell;
```

But the subtitles are the same in every cell: **( 2, 2) countries** instead of 2 countries in the first cell and 2 countries in the second one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *ContinentName = [world objectForKey:indexPath.row];
```

the `objectForKey` is expecting a name for the key, you´re giving in an `int`.

try this:

```
NSDictionary *ContinentName = [world objectForKey:@"Europe"];
```

Also, the value returning here is a `NSDictionary`, not a String.

I recommend converting your continents to a flat array.

```
NSMutableArray *flatArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]; 
for(id item in world){
    [flatArray addObject:item];
}
```

This array you can access via the `indexPath.row`

If you want the names of the continents you can call.

```
NSArray *namesOfContintents = [world allKeys];
```

Comment: When I added "NSArray *flatArray …" I received an error: no visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'addObject:'             Could you write the whole 'tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath' block?

Comment: sorry, it has to be NSMutableArray. The Array part is a bonus. Focus on what I wrote before, you assigning a NSDictionary to an NSString.

Comment: Yes, I see it now but still don't know how to overcome that issue. :( Maybe I should reorganise my plist to make it easier to use?

Comment: Yes! I got it! I added: NSArray *namesOfContintents = [world allKeys];
    NSString *ContinentName = [namesOfContintents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    cell.textLabel.text = ContinentName; and it's working now

Comment: Any help how to get number of countries as subtitles? (I edited my main topics to provide more info)

Comment: can you please start a new issue about it and show what exactly is not working for that new issue. Im sure more people can help you then.