# UITableView cell subtitles from plist data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I  want to add some subtitles to my UITableView cells (where I display continents, countries, other data). Already populated my first table with continents. Now I want to add numbers of countries as subtitle in every continent cell. I added:

```
int numberEurope;
numberEurope = [europe count]; //this works fine

int numberAfrica;
numberAfrica = [africa count]; //this works fine

NSNumber *myNum1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:numberEurope];
NSNumber *myNum2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:numberAfrica];

NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: myNum1, myNum2, nil];

cell.textLabel.text = ContinentName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ countries", myArray];
return cell;
```

But the subtitles are the same in every cell, the full array is shown: **( 2, 2) countries** instead of 2 countries in the first cell and 2 countries in the second one. What am I doing wrong? The plist I use is screenshot here: [Cannot Feed UITableView with .plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371773/cannot-feed-uitableview-with-plist)

Comment: And where exactly you have a code that you expect to select proper number for given cell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select proper value based on indexPath:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d countries", [[myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] intValue]];
```

Comment: This exactly what I wanted. Thank you - will remember that part for the future issues.